# If parent div has more than 1 child div, so add-class to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I added on my site a div, which sometimes displays 1 child div and sometimes more than 1 and I want add a class to Body tag if the childs div are 1 if not give to body another class.

I tried this code, but it did not work :

**JavaScript**

```
setInterval(function(){
if(jQuery('div#program-days .row').length > 1)
    jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass1');
else
    jQuery('body').removeClass('bodyclass2');
}, 1000);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="program-days">
    <div class="row">program 1</div>
    <div class="row">program 2</div>
    <div class="row">program 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: setInterval(function(){
if(jQuery('div#program-days .row').length > 1)
    jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass1');
else
    jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass2');
}, 1000); You gave removeclass...

Comment: That should work (though the `div` part of `div#program-days` doesn't serve any purpose except in a very unusual situation you probably don't have). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Although you've said *"...if not give to body another class..."* but your `else` block doesn't do that, it *removes* another class. Perhaps you meant `addClass('bodyclass2')` rather than `removeClass('bodyclass2')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should removeClass and addClass like this

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(jQuery('div#program-days .row').length > 1){
        jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass1');
         jQuery('body').removeClass('bodyclass2');
        }
    else{

        jQuery('body').removeClass('bodyclass1');
        jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass2');
        }
    }, 1000);
```

```js
setInterval(function(){
if(jQuery('div#program-days .row').length > 1){
    jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass1');
     jQuery('body').removeClass('bodyclass2');
    }
else{

    jQuery('body').removeClass('bodyclass1');
    jQuery('body').addClass('bodyclass2');
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.bodyclass1{
background-color:red;
}
.bodyclass2{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="program-days">
    <div class="row">program 1</div>
    <div class="row">program 2</div>
    <div class="row">program 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this works for a simplified example, if you have any `.row` in `.row` you'll get unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code, up on click on try now the class will be added to the body if childs are more than one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <!-- This is a comment node! -->
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <div id="program-days">
        <div class="row">program 1</div>
        <div class="row">program 2</div>
        <div class="row">program 3</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var parent = document.getElementById("program-days");
            if (parent.childNodes.length > 1) {
                document.body.classList.add('myclass');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont remove the other class when you add the class:

Here is an example using non-jQuery:

Javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var els = document.querySelectorAll("#program-days .row");
  var body = document.querySelector("body");

  if (els.length > 1) {
    body.classList.add("red-border");
    body.classList.remove("blue-border");
  } else {
    body.classList.add("blue-border");
    body.classList.remove("red-border");
  }
}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="program-days">
      <div class="row">program 1</div>
      <div class="row">program 2</div>
      <div class="row">program 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.red-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blue-border {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ATP63ZWXASTwFaG2jM3y?p=preview

It can be done with jQuery aswell, using your syntax.